# Rails development: how to respond to several requests at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, mongrel, webrick, multiprocess

I have inherited the maintenance of a legacy web-application with an "interesting" way to manage concurrent access to the database.

The application is based on ruby-on-rails 2.3.8.

I'd like to set up a development environment and from there have two web browser make simultaneous requests, just to get the gist of what is going on.

Of course this is not going to work if I use Webrick, since it services just one http request at a time, so all the requests are effectively serialized by it.

I thought that mongrel could help me, but

```
mongrel_rails start -n 5
```

is actually spawning a single process and it seems to be single-threaded, too.

What is the easiest way of setting my development environment so that it responds to more than one request at a time? I'd like to avoid using apache and mod_passenger because, this being development, I'd like to be able to change the code and have it reloaded automatically on the next request.

Answer (score 1):

In development mode, mod_passenger does reload classes and views.  I use passenger exclusively for both development and deployment.

In production, you can (from the root of the rails app):

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

and passenger will reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at thin

http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/

Comment: Well, by default `thin` seems to only respond to one request at a time. I tried using the servers command line parameter `thin --servers 10` but this seems to just spawn several instances of thin listening on different ports -- but I'd like to have a single url for my app. Am I missing something?

Comment: You may have to use `thin --threaded`. According to the docs, it `Calls the Rack application in threads`.